# MYSQL server has gone away., cant find reason why

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am currently trying to upload an image to my database.

This normally works but I have added code to watermark the image. The watermark works but now when I try to upload the image I get these errors.

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in F:\xxamp\htdocs\attempt3\Admin\NewPhoto2.php on line 162

Warning: mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in F:\xxamp\htdocs\attempt3\Admin\NewPhoto2.php on line 162
```

The servers max packet is easily big enough and the query itself takes a few seconds so I cannot understand the problem.

I have been reading this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

But I am no closer to understanding.

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
$_POST['name'] = addslashes($_POST['name']);
$_POST['price'] = addslashes($_POST['price']);
$_POST['molding'] = addslashes($_POST['molding']);
$_POST['frame'] = addslashes($_POST['frame']);
$_POST['cat'] = addslashes($_POST['cat']);
$image = imagecreatefromstring ($image);

// Load the stamp and the photo to apply watermark to

$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermark2.PNG');

$save_watermark_photo_address = 'watermark_photo2.jpg';

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height or width of the stamp image

$marge_right = 0;
$marge_bottom = 0;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);


$imgx = imagesx($image);
$imgy = imagesy($image);
$centerX=round($imgx/2) - ($sx/2);
$centerY=round($imgy/2) - ($sy/2);
// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 

imagecopy($image, $stamp, $centerX, $centerY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

imagejpeg($image, $save_watermark_photo_address, 80);

ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();





$insert = "INSERT INTO photo (name, photo, cat, framesug, moldsug, price)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','$contents','".$_POST['cat']."','".$_POST['frame']."','".$_POST['molding']."','".$_POST['price']."')";
mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
```

The problem started when I added this code.

```
   ob_start();
    imagepng($image);
    $contents =  ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Why do you want to store png-file contents in a db instead of storing file on disk and path to it in a db?

Comment: I don't save the path in the db, the image is saved as a blob in the db.

Comment: And I ask you why do you do this?

Comment: Oh ok well when researching about doing this every single website and every single stackoverflow question/answer i read said its best to do it this way.

Comment: research again, because most good sites recommends only storing path on DB. Also try access DB using libraries, that support reconnection.

Comment: Alot of things can happen when storing PNG source in the database and cause complications which cannot always be spotted on initial debugging, IE you retrieve the blob field with the wrong character set which will corrupt the file when trying to print it. as @ViliusL has mentioned. It's BEST to store the path to the PNG in the database and load via the disk